# TypeORM to_tsquery Injection prevention

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I want to perform a full-text-search on 2 columns with partial queries included.

I've tried multiple options and this one seems the best to me:

1. Add <-> between the words of the query and :* at the end
2. Execute query

The problem is, that I have to execute the query in TypeORM. So when I use `to_tsquery(:query)` there might be invalid syntax in the query, which produces an error.

The function `plainto_tsquery()` would be perfect since it prevents invalid syntax in the argument, but at the same time it prevents the partial queries, which I can do as described.

Any idea how I could combine the best of the to worlds?

Comment: Errors occur when the given query includes separated single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT to_tsquery(quote_literal(query) || ':*')
```

This will add <-> between word and :* at the end of every word, while quote_literal should protect you from syntax issues by escaping the text.

Disadvantage of this method however is that the generated query might behave unexpectedly when encountering queries with symbols, e.g. o'reilley as query will yield 'o':* <-> 'reilley':* as tsquery, which likely won't give back the expected result. Unfortunately, the only solution I know for this is cleaning both the input and text data of any symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I solved the problem by using an inline if-else in the query to figure out wheter to add ":*" or not.